# how to load a delimited file into excel specific sheet using a delimiter other than ","

Tags: excel, powershell

In PowerShell, how to load a delimited file into Excel specific sheet using a delimiter other than `,` (say for example the file is delimited with `;`).

I am aware of how to load a CSV file into a sheet using:

```
$processes = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
...
```

However, this assumes:

1. Data goes to sheet1 (I need to specify the target sheet name and create it if not there).
2. The input file is CSV, in my case, the delimiter may be other than ",".

I considered replacing the delimiter with a `,` before load, but somehow it does not look neat, since commas may exist inside literals (for example c1;"two;strings";c3).

I am not asking for complete code, just a pointer or a reference will serve me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Open()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) method:

```
$file  = 'C:\path\to\file'
$undef = [Type]::Missing
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file, $undef, $undef, 6, $undef, $undef, $undef, $undef, ';')
```

or the [`OpenText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) method:

```
$file  = 'C:\path\to\file'
$undef = [Type]::Missing
$excel.Workbooks.OpenText($file, $undef, $undef, 1, $undef, $undef, $undef, $undef, $undef, $undef, $true, ';')
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Item(1)
```

Note that the `OpenText()` method does not return a workbook object, so you must assign the workbook to a variable yourself after opening the file.

Note also that the file must not have the extension .csv if the delimiter character differs from the delimiter defined in the system's regional settings, otherwise the delimiter will be ignored.

Comment: I had no idea about the `$undef` usage like that. That is spectacular info for anybody that uses any of the Office interops much.

Comment: Thank you for your clear example. I used a similar code years before when I had to invoke Excel from VB6...At least somethings did not change!

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions, so let's address them in order.

> Data goes to sheet1 (I need to specify the target sheet name and
>   create it if not there).

So then specify the sheet, there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

```
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $XL.Open("$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\SuperImportant.xlsx")
$WS = $WB.Worksheets.Items("MySheet")
$WS.Select()
```

Need to make it if it's not there? Ok, just make a check first.

```
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $XL.Open("$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\SuperImportant.xlsx")
If(!"MySheet" -in $WB.Worksheets.Name){
    $WB.Worksheets.Add("MySheet")
}
$WS = $WB.Worksheets.Items("MySheet")
$WS.Select()
```

Ok, that issue is handled.

> The input file is CSV, in my case, the delimiter may be other than ",".

Ansgar Wiechers already showed you how to import the file directly into Excel, so I'll take the PowerShell as a proxy approach. You can specify that when you import it into PowerShell using `Import-Csv`.

```
$MyData = Import-Csv C:\Path\To\MyFile.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Then you just copy it to the clipboard (as a tab delimited CSV) and paste it into Excel.

```
$MyData | ConvertTo-CSV -Del "`t" -NoType | Clip
$XL.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial()
```

Comment: Thank you for your clean explanation. I like your clear coding approach. I find that copying the data to clipboard makes the code easier, but I am not sure if that will work in case I get large files. Once more thank you very much.